# ImageButton in UpdatePanel doesn't PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I created a form in a popup div, that contain an UpdatePanel with ImageButtons in it.

Initially, I used LinkButtons to test but I wanted ImageButtons. The thing is, it works well with LinkButtons and not with ImageButtons (absolutely nothing happens).

Checking the source, I see that the javascript call is a little different :
LinkButton :

> ```
> <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
> WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cphC$ctrlAdr$AdrMapo$lbAdresseSaisie&quot;,
> &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;,
> &quot;&quot;, false, true))"
> id="ctl00_cphC_ctrlAdr_AdrMapo_lbAdresseSaisie">test</a>
> ```

ImageButton :

> ```
> <input align="absmiddle" type="image" style="border-width:0px;"
> onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
> WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cphC$ctrlAdr$AdrMapo$rpAdressesProposees$ctl00$ibAdresseProposee&quot;,
> &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;,
> &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
> ...>
> ```

After checking the doc, I see that the last parameter of `WebForm_PostBackOptions` is called `clientSubmit` and if it is set to `true` a submit is performed.
For the ImageButton this value is set to `false` and if I change it to `true` manually with Firebug, it works as expected.
But I can't find anywhere a way to change that parameter when the control is drawn. And that's quite annoying.

If I set `ImageButton.CausesValidation`, there is no javascript generated and nothing happen when I click on the button.
The UpdatePanel is declared like this :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAdressesProposees" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" Visible="true">
```

And to be sure I declared a trigger for the ImageButton.
I use `UpdateMode="conditional"` because it needs to be updatable programmingly from outside of the UpdatePanel events.

The LinkButton submits correctly in exactly the same situation so I don't know what I did wrong here...

Comment: Note : I'm expecting an AsyncPostBack.

Comment: And I have the same issue with `Button`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any client side validation being performed that is blocking the postback? Does it do a postback if you remove the UpdatePanel from the page? I would test that so you determine if it is a problem with the UpdatePanel + ImageButton or just the Imagebutton.

Comment: It's not the Validation : if I change manually the javascript's last parameter, it's still validating but submits after.
And with CausesValidation = false it doesn't work either. It's a UserControl inside another UserControl with several UpdatePanels in each level so I guess it has something to do with that... If I remove my own UpdatePanel it still doesn't work but I can't edit Parent controls...